# large number array in AutoCompleteTextView in Android

Tags: android, arrays, autocompletetextview

I need to show the city name in the suggestions of `AutoCompleteTextView`.
I have saved all names in an array in `res/values/strings.xml` .
But it is a large number array. It's near about **15,000** names.

But I worried it may create some memory issue .Is there any other way to save this amount of data in android?

I think the best way is to create a web-service, but is there any other solution available instead of web-services because I am not very familiar with web-services?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having large data, then it is better to go for ListViews rather than going for AutoCompleteTextView. Add search functionality to that Listview by keeping a Textview on top of that Listview. Every Adapter is having [getFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getFilter%28%29)

by which we can filter the List. It is also easy.

**The second option:** keep your strings.xml in XML or raw folder and parse it using sax or Dom parser.

Finally, As per my knowledge, keeping the data in strings.xml the apk size will be increased but not the heap. Even if you bring the XML from local or Webservice, anyway you need to keep it in the Heap at all the ways.